# How to add Date(month) that will show in right order, right now it goes backward in recursion CTE SQL

Tags: sql, date, recursive-query

```
with recursive cte (id, qty) (
    select id, qty from mytable
    union all
    select id, qty - 1 from cte where qty > 1
)
select id from cte order by id
```

Question:

How to add Date(month) that will show in right order, right now it goes backward in recursion CTE ?

```
with recursive cte (id, qty, Forecast_date) 
( 
select id, qty, StartDate from mytable 
union all 
select id, qty - 1, eomonth(dateadd(month, 1,Forecast_date)) from cte where qty > 1 ) 

select id,Forecast_date from cte order by id
```

Output:

```
9/30/2023   0
8/31/2023   1
7/31/2023   2
6/30/2023   3
5/31/2023   4
4/30/2023   5
3/31/2023   6
2/28/2023   7
1/31/2023   8
12/31/2022  9
11/30/2022  10
10/31/2022  11
9/30/2022   12
8/31/2022   13
7/31/2022   14
6/30/2022   15
5/31/2022   16
...
```

Expected incremental starting 5/31/2022 and not starting 2023-09-30 which should be last record

The point to get:

```
Id  Forecast_date  qty
1   5/31/2022      0
2   6/30/2022      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the number of months in the seed Select:

```
with recursive cte (id, qty, Forecast_date) 
(
select id, qty, eomonth(dateadd(month, -qty,StartDate)) 
from mytable 
union all 
select id, qty - 1, eomonth(dateadd(month, 1,Forecast_date)) 
from cte 
where qty >= 1 
) 

select * 
from cte 
order by id, qty
```

Or add another column, start with qty 0 and count up instead of count down:

```
with recursive cte (id, qty, Forecast_date, stopat)
( 
select id, 0, StartDate, qty
from mytable 
union all 
select id, qty + 1, eomonth(dateadd(month, 1,Forecast_date)), stopat
from cte 
where qty < stopat 
) 

select id, qty, Forecast_date
from cte 
order by id, qty
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to start by generating an incrementing sequence, and then do the computation in the outer query:

```
with recursive cte (id, qty, forecast_date, lvl) (
    select id, qty, datefromparts(year(forecast_date), month(forecast_date), 1), 0 lvl from mytable
    union all
    select id, qty, forecast_date, lvl + 1 from cte where lvl < qty
)
select 
    id,
    qty - lvl as dty,
    eomonth(dateadd(month, -lvl, forecast_date)) new_forecast_date
from cte
order by id, new_forecast_date
```

End of month computation is tricky: you  cannot jump from an end of month to another by adding months, since not all months have the same number of days. So the query uses the beginning of the starting month for the computation, *then* uses `eomonth()`.